# Autoexpanding textarea with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, textarea

I need the `<textarea>` to vertically grows as the user types in and I found this code on the net http://perplexed.co.uk/596_expanding_textarea_as_you_type.htm
I want it to be written in `jQuery` but as I turn the code into `jQuery` it does not work.

This is the javascript version:

```
<textarea id="text"></textarea>

var textArea = document.getElementById('text')
textArea.addEventListener('input', function () {
    while (
    textArea.rows > 1 && textArea.scrollHeight < textArea.offsetHeight) {
        textArea.rows--;
    }
    var h = 0;
    while (textArea.scrollHeight > textArea.offsetHeight && h !== textArea.offsetHeight) {
        h = textArea.offsetHeight;
        textArea.rows++;
    }
    textArea.rows++
});
```

**fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/dcdeiv/dsL6g/3/

however I don't want to use an ID or a class, I want that to work for each textarea, so I tryed to use an **each** function:

```
<textarea></textarea>

$.fn.growRows = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var textArea     = $( this ),
            scrollHeight = textArea.scrollTop(),
            offsetHeight = textArea.height(),
            rows         = textArea.attr( rows ),
            h            = 0;

        textArea.keyup(function() {

            while ( rows > 1 && scrollHeight < offsetHeight ) {
                rows--;
            }

            while ( scrollHeight > offsetHeight && h !== offsetHeight ) {
                h = offsetHeight;
                rows++;
            }
            rows++;
        });
    });
}

$( 'textarea' ).growRows();
```

but it does not work anyway.

**fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/dcdeiv/BQB4M/

Comment: http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be what you're looking for but check out my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanolsonx/FZ37m/). Code below as well:

```
$.fn.growRows = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var textArea = $(this);

        textArea.on('keyup', function() {
            textArea[0].rows = textArea.val().split('\n').length || 1;
        });

        textArea.trigger('keyup'); //set initial size
    });
};

$('textarea').growRows();
```

Also, in your fiddle, you had a few javascript errors that could prevent you from getting it working.  You need to include jQuery as a library in JSFiddle and textArea.attr( rows ) needs to actually be textArea.attr( 'rows' ).  Please note that even if you make these changes, your fiddle does not work.  When you inc/dec your rows variable, nothing will happen.

Comment: Well it is really simple and in few lines, so it is exactly what I looked for! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If your only concern is about getting all `textarea`'s not depending of `classes/ids`, it is still **possible** to do without `jquery` by using `getElementsByTagName('textarea')`. Then, to achieve the autoexpanding we need to bind an *event listener* to each of the `textarea`'s obtained, doing some changes to original code, we get:

**HTML:**

```
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var textArea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea'); //get all textareas
for (var i = 0; i <= textArea.length-1; i++) {            //loop through textareas
  textArea[i].addEventListener('input', function () {     //binds listener 
    while (
    this.rows > 1 && this.scrollHeight < this.offsetHeight) {
        this.rows--;
    }

    var h = 0;
    while (this.scrollHeight > this.offsetHeight && h !== this.offsetHeight) {
        h = this.offsetHeight;
        this.rows++;
    }

    this.rows++
  });
}
```

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/dsL6g/6/